# Run function before all tests in PHPUniit

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I am looking at PHPunit for running Selenium tests and can run tests fine. What's missing though is the ability to run a function before the tests are run (let's say to set up some config).

```
<?php

require_once 'SeleniumTest.php';

class MyTest extends SeleniumTest
{

  public function testTest1()
  {
    $this->runSelenese(__DIR__ . '/test1.html');
  }

  public function testTest2()
  {
    $this->runSelenese(__DIR__ . '/test2.html');
  }
}
```

The config file is just a regular html file, but needs to be run once before anything else is run

### Edit

Another read of the setUp() function has led me to believe that my tests should be setup as follows.

What I want to simulate is a user logging in, setting up some config, running the test and then logging out of the application at the end of the test.

This is what I have come up with; please advise on what I have done wrong, as the tests don't run at the moment. All tests timeout: is this how I should be approaching this?

```
<?php

require_once 'SeleniumTest.php';

class MyTest extends SeleniumTest
{

  public function setUp()
  {
    $login_path = '/login_path/Login.html';
    $logout_path = '/logout_path/Logout.html';  
    $config_path = '/config_path/config.html';
    $this->runSelenese($login_path);
    $this->runSelenese($config_path);
    $this->runSelenese($logout_path);
  }

  public function testTest1()
  {
    $this->runSelenese(__DIR__ . '/test1.html');
  }

 public function testTest2()
 {
    $this->runSelenese(__DIR__ . '/test2.html');
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a [setup()](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.more-setup-than-teardown) method?

Comment: will this only run once? or before each test?

Comment: It runs before every single test, that's the point of it. As each test runs it isolation, how could it be otherwise

Comment: ah right, but I only want to run my config/html file once before ALL tests, so if i have 20 tests, config is only run once

Comment: May be `--bootstrap` will do what you need - [https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html)

Comment: @MarkBaker would you mind looking at my edit please?